# How to get path of file (vidéo/picture) inside external SDCard of any android

Tags: cordova, android-sdcard

It's so easy to have path of file on internal storage by using cordova-plugin-file; eg: file:///SDCard/
But I need to have exact code for external SDCard.

I try to use cordova-plugin-file, cordova-plugin-media, cordova.plugins.diagnostic but all time have and error.